# Use of array.map with a function with three parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function using Array.map() that takes 3 parameters: an array, a function that doubles the elements of the array and the number of times to perform the function.

For example, if I had `([1, 2, 3], double, 2)` it would return `[4, 8, 12]`.

My code so far:

```js
const feedback = (array, func, num) => {
  return array.map(func)
}

// Helper function
function double(element) {
  return element * 2;
}
```

I'm struggling with how to incorporate the third parameter num. Since I need to repeat the function n number of times, I'm thinking I need a for loop? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the callback function of `.map()` gets executed for every element in the array just saying. you would also know it if you would read just the first sentece https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I don't see why an additional for or while loop wouldn't work here. Just store the result of `func` into a variable on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is needed to call `func` for `num` times inside `Array.map` callback as follows.

```js
const feedback = (array, func, num) => {
  return array.map((item) => {
    let val = func(item);
    for (let i = 0; i < num - 1; i ++) {
      val = func(val);
    }
    return val;
  });
}

// Helper function
function double(element) {
  return element * 2;
}

console.log(feedback([1,2,3], double, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the help of `Array#from`, `Array#map` and `Array#reduce`.

The `Array#from` would help in to do the operation `num` times (by creating a *temp* array) and the `Array#reduce` will accumulate the values after applying the operation `num` times into a *single* array:

```js
const feedback = (array, func, num) => {
  return Array.from({length: num}).reduce(r => r.map(double), array);
}


const double = (element) => {
  return element * 2;
}

console.log(feedback([1, 2, 3], double, 0));
console.log(feedback([1, 2, 3], double, 1));
console.log(feedback([1, 2, 3], double, 2));
console.log(feedback([1, 2, 3], double, 3));
console.log(feedback([1, 2, 3], double, 4));
```

Comment: This creates so many arrays... If `reduce` is to be used, why not just use functional composition? Generate an array of `num` times the function, then compose them together into one function that applies `func` multiple times. https://jsbin.com/jefuselire/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Oops typo. That link should have been https://jsbin.com/duhohagase/1/edit?js,console